# Can the Reincarnate Wild Magic Surge work more than once within the minute?

Tags: dnd-5e, wild-magic

One of the effects of the Wild Magic Surge table is that if you die within 1 minute, you get the effect of the Reincarnate spell.

The description doesn’t state “the first time you die” or “everytime you die”, so would it work multiple times if you die repeatedly within a minute ?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the DM rules - the words support either interpretation.